# Joining several csvs to create one large file. Some csvs have different columns names, how to handle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that id like to concatenate into one large file.

I noticed that the columns are not unique in each file. A handful of columns have the word "package" in the column.  I want to replace "package" with "pkg".

I pulled in the complete list of .csvs using the glob method and then I combined the data together using pd.concat

data1.csv

data2.csv

```
grouped data result example:

package dimension   package height  package length  pkg dimensions  pkg height  pkg length
1                       10                4             6               11         9
2                       15                5             7               16         21
3                       30                6             8               31         7
```

Data should be:

```
    pkg dimensions  pkg height  pkg length                          
    6                   11      9
    7                   16      21
    8                   31      7
    1                   10      4
    2                   15      5
    3                   30      6
```

I have a dictionary of all the correct column names for example:

```
df.rename(columns ={'package dimension' : 'pkg dimensions' etc})
```

Rather than opening up each excel file and renaming the column I want to a list comprehension. Here's what I got so far:

```
data = list of all excel file locations
i in range(len(data):
    df = pd.read_csv(fedex[i], index_col=0)
    df = df.rename(columns ={'package dimension' : 'pkg dimensions' etc}, inplace=True)
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i).assign(filename= os.path.basename(i)) for i in data), ignore_index = True)
```

I cant figure out how to rename the columns and put them in place properly. After I run this it works but I end up with 91 columns or 11 extra.

Comment: Did you try stripping the column values? Have a look at what extra columns are created.

Comment: yah so this file is pulled daily and I think the column name was a typo. the column name Should have been pkg but was typed package. so when I try and concat all the csvs I get a dataframe with both package and pkg columns and I just wanted the pkg columns. So my thought was once I change the column names and THEN join I wouldnt get the extra columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['package dimension',  'package height',  'package length'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('package','pkg')
print(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['pkg dimension', 'pkg height', 'pkg length'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I tried that and it was able to rename the columns! But when I did len(df.columns) I still had 91 columns and I should have 80 columns.

Comment: I guess column names may have something unnecessary like spaces, so rename does not work. You can use list(set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns)) and list(set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns)) to examine which column names are different in two dataframes.